# Replace character in JavaScript String

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have a variable which holds strings similar to this:

```
var color = 'Red | Rich Blue | White |';
```

I need to convert this into this format:

```
var color = 'Color: Red<br>Color: Rich Blue<br>Color: White';
```

Using PHP I know how to do this but not with JavaScript, would appreciate any help please

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: as mentioned I do not know how to do with JavaScript

Comment: How *would* you write it in PHP? The same process(es) can be used in JavaScript.. Two approaches that would work 1) use a regular expression; or 2) split the colors (or whatever) to an array and then create a new string from the array data.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an approach that works by splitting the string into an array, then enumerating the results and building a new string.

```js
var newColor = '';
var color = 'Red | Rich Blue | White |';
color.split('|').forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.length)
    newColor += "Color: " + item + "<br>";
});

alert(newColor);
```

Comment: thanks just what I was looking for, didn't know of this `split` method!

Comment: You have an `Color: <br>` at the end of the string. When you split it by `|`, you also get an empty element as the last element of the array.

Comment: @RocoCTZ thanks, I added a fix for that

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with @Dave, but:
color.split('|').forEach generates an error if there's no pipeline in the string, thus a foreach on no-array.

```
var newColor = '';
var color = 'Red | Rich Blue | White';
var splittedColors = color.split('|');

if (splittedColors.length > 0)
{
    splittedColors.forEach(function(item)
    {
        newColor += "Color: " + item + "<br>";
    });
} 

alert(newColor);
```

Comment: Why should `color.split('|').forEach` throw an error if there is no `|` in the string? [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) always returns an array.

Comment: @Andreas, only if you want to loop.

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript, for example:

```
    var color = 'Red | Rich Blue | White |';
    var arr = color.split('|');
    var str = "";
    for(var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
    {
      str += "Color: " + arr[n] + " <br> ";
    }
```

Comment: My answer was pure JavaScript as well